# Cannot create database from Doctrine command "orm:schema-tool:create"

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am following this tutorial.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

I am using `mysql` instead of `sqlite`.

Following command should create the database.

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

But it is not creating any. If i manually create the database, following command works fine

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

Any idea why that command is not working?

Doctrine version 2.4.1

Comment: what is the error msg in the cli after this:    php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create ?

Comment: did you tell your config all about your mysql connection? database, user, password ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this link:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

User doctrine-module instead of doctrine.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: this saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar issue and found that the command below

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Doesn't create the DB itself, it only creates the schema/tables.

I solved this by doing the following:

```
<?php
include 'bootstrap.php';
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

try {
    $entityManager->getConnection()->connect();
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    $connection = EntityManager::create([
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'host'     => MYSQL_HOST,
        'user'     => MYSQL_USERNAME,
        'password' => MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        'charset' => 'UTF8'
    ], $config)->getConnection();
    $connection->executeUpdate('CREATE DATABASE '.MYSQL_DATABASE.' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci');
}
return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
?>
```

Basically the script attempts to connect to the specified database, if that fails it attempts to create the database (assuming that the user is allowed to perform database creation that is - might be prudent to delete this file
after deployment).

Source: http://www.cstruter.com/blog/395